# StackOverflow error while using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

I am trying to get the number (n) to (m) and to me the algorithm makes sense yet it always crashes with a Stackoverflow error. any help?
here's my code:

```
private static int solve(int n, int m, int steps) {

    if (n > m || n <= 0) {
        //--steps;
        return 0;
    } else if (n == m)
        return steps;

    return Math.min(solve(n * 2, m, steps++), solve(n - 1, m, steps++));
}
```

Update:::
this code solve this problem very elegantly

```
private static int solve(int n, int m) {

    int steps = 0;
    int cur = n;
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();

   //Setting a list of the best minimum track.
    arr.add(m);
    for (int i = 0; !arr.contains(1); ++i)
        arr.add((int) Math.round((double) arr.get(i) / 2));

   //Aligning the number n to the track and applying it to the best track.(Imagine a stair of steps and you have to reach the top of it, you'll align yourself to one of the steps and then voooom :) )
    while (cur != m) {
        if (arr.contains(cur))
            cur *= 2;
        else
            cur--;

        steps++;
    }
    return steps;
}
```

Comment: Well, what values are you starting with? What diagnostics steps have you taken to check what's happening? Have you tried debugging through the code?

Comment: One hint: a call to `solve(2, 3)` requires a call to `solve(1, 3)`... which in turn makes a call to `solve(2, 3)`... how did you *expect* that to be resolved? (It's not clear what you're trying to compute, to be honest...)

Comment: I'll take "infinite recursion" for 200, Alex.

Comment: **Suggestion:** your `return` statement is incrementing variables while it's also making a calculation.  That's too hard to reason about; *separate the increment step from the calculation step.*

Comment: @JonSkeet I am trying with values like 4 , 6
your testcase is right but not always; as number 1 has a special case; what I'm saying is let's try 4,6

Comment: So your case of (4, 6) will still call (3, 6) which calls (2, 6) which calls (4, 6) again. Again - how did you expect that to work?

Comment: I feel so bad, I get what you mean
any suggestions to avoid that ?
@JonSkeet

Comment: @HossamEl-DinDoma there's a mathematical way of solving the problem you're trying to solve. I'll post a link to the answer as soon as I've found the post.

Comment: We can't tell what you're trying to achieve, so it's hard to know what to suggest - but basically, this is an algorithmic problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: @HossamEl-DinDoma found the non-recursive arithmetic solution. It's a bit more complex, but the efficiency is way beyond anything your algorithm would achieve even in the best case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808907/bfs-for-arithmetic-operations/34810686#34810686

Comment: @Paul much thanks for that efficient solution, but I'm trying here to solve it by recursion and hopefully avoid the mistake I made; I mean can you walk me through avoiding re-visiting already visited nodes
thanks anyway for all

Comment: @HossamEl-DinDoma simply add a `Set` of visited integers to the parameter list and hand the set down each recursion-step adding already visited values. The main-problem here would be that a DFS will never find the solution to your problem. You'll have to use BFS.

Comment: @HossamEl-DinDoma I've edited my answer with a solution that produces the solution using recursion

Comment: what is the goal of this function ?

Comment: @Paul Much appreciated sir :)

Comment: @Navid you have number n what is the shortest path to m
you can only multiply by 2 or subtract by 1
check sir, Paul answer in the comments

Comment: Are you supposed to use only recursive function? I mean is this some kind of homework assignment ?
or you are free to do use any way ?

Comment: @Navid
Sorry for the delay, but no I just want it recursively already did it iteratively

Comment: This is question has been disallowed for being answered.

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm always traverses **all** possible paths in a tree where one branch represents multiplication and one decrement by 1. The problem is the "**all**", since there would as well be a path like this:

```
n = 2 m = 5
branch selection  *2 -1 -1 *2 -1 -1 *2 ...
n after branch     4  3  2  4  3  2  4 ...
```

Which will never abort.

And I doubt that this algorithm will, though it makes perfect sense to you and apart from the obvious issue with the `StackOverflowException` will solve your problem in all cases. Just a guess, but the problem is to find the minimum-number of multiplications and decrements required to transform `n` to `m`. This algorithm will for nearly all cases return 0.

A correct solution would require BFS, unlike the (incorrect) DFS-implementation your solution uses. There is an additional `Set` for visited nodes required to implement a correct DFS-traversal, invalid solutions would have to be marked explicitly. BFS on the other hand would aswell require to store the depth at which the value was visited:

```
public int solve(int n , int m , int step , Map<Integer , Integer> visitedAt){
    //no valid solution  
    if(n > m * 2 || n <= 0)
        return -1;

    //a solution was found at step
    if(n == m)
        return step;

    //the node was already visited with less steps
    if(visitedAt.containsKey(n) && visitedAt.get(n) <= step)
        return -1;

    //store the visited value and the step at which it was visited
    visitedAt.put(n , step);
    //calculate the number of steps required to reach m if the next step is
    //either decrement or multiply by two
    int dec = solve(n - 1 , m , step + 1 , visitedAt);
    int mul = solve(n * 2 , m , step + 1 , visitedAt);

    if(dec == -1)//no possibility to reach m by decrementing n
        return mul;
    else if(mul == -1)//cant reach m by multiplying n by 2
        return dec;
    else //both lead to valid solutions, find minimum number of steps
        return Math.min(dec , mul);
}
```

Though this solution isn't exactly an elegant implementation of the BFS-algorithm. But it fulfills the requirement of being recursive.

Comment: this doesn't work. Try solve(1,5,0)

Comment: @Navid sry, I've just noticed that I copied another mistake made in the code provided by OP. I'll correct that. Should work now for your sample-input.

Comment: @Navid I've also updated the post with the arithmetic solution mr.paul suggested. works fine with a very efficient time complexity.